# android 4.0 chrome remote debugging shortcut

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, android

I'm a web designer and I'm currently in the process of designing a mobile site, i know how to set it up in my command prompt to allow chrome and the adb to reach my phone for debugging the mobile site, my only problem is each time the phone gets disconnected (happens quite frequently due to bad usb ports) I have to rerun the entire script. I want to create a shortcut on my desktop so that it will allow me to just double click the shortcut and I'm good to go from there.

I've tried using the target as

```
"C:\Users\Editor 8\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -adb -forward -tcp:9222 -localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote
```

The part listed as

```
adb forward tcp:9222 -localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote
```

tells the adb connection to allow me to debug the mobile browser so it would be like the options parameters.

My problem is that each time I've attempted this my command prompt opens long enough for my adb terminal to run through the 'help' section like I'd input a wrong command then closes. 
Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also noticed that when removing the options it did the exact same thing of opening the help window then closing it immediately after

Comment: Why not open a command prompt? `Start` -> Type `cmd` in the search box (vista and 7) and press enter will open a command prompt that you can copy/paste your shortcut or batch file into.  That should let you see if it is coming up with an error or something.